# React-Native Offline Bundle - Images not showing

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have a React-Native app I'm trying to deploy in Release mode to my phone. I can bundle the app to the phone. Database, Video and audio assets are all in there but no images are showing in the UI.

I have done the following to 'bundle' my app:

1. in the project folder in Terminal run `react-native bundle --platfrom ios --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output main.jsbundle`
2. Drag the reference to the `main.jsbundle` file into XCode under `myapp` folder
3. In XCode, open `AppDelegate.m` and uncomment `jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle]…`
4. Open `Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme` then change `Build Configuration` to `Release`
5. Select `myapp` under the project navigator and then:
   under `TARGETS: myappTests` > `Build Phases` > `Link Binary With Libraries`
   press `+`
   select `Workspace` > `libReact.a` and `Add`

When I try and compile in XCode with the `../node_modules/react-native/packager/react-native-xcode.sh` setting in `myapp > targets > myapp > Bundle React Native code and images` it fails with `error code 1`.

I've seen LOADS of posts on this and I've tried:

- to check `Run script only when installing`- the app then installs but with no images
- adding `source ~/.bash_profile` to react-native-xcode.sh - the app build fails

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have the same issue, did you resolve this?

Comment: as yet no but my colleague is fairly certain is is something to do the way my node installation is aliased...we need to look into it. He can bundle in the same way and everything works.

Answer (score 29):

When you are generating bundle , Also put --assets-dest ./

`react-native bundle --platform ios --assets-dest ./ --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output iOS/main.jsbundle`

It will generate `main.jsbundle` and Assets folder . Go to your Xcode right click add files to project and add `main.jsbundle` file to project. Also drag and drop Assets folder and select create by reference (note: do not select create group).

i was using react 0.33,
main.jsbundle is using assets(small a) folder but generating Assets(Caps A). I just changed the generated folder from Assets to assets and import it to xcode and it start working

Comment: Apparently, it is indeed all the difference to select `create by reference` rather than `create groups`. You can then add the `assets` folder as a whole in `Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources` rather than each individual asset file, which seems to mess with RN's ability to find them.

Comment: Also drag and drop Assets folder and select create by reference (note: do not select create group). (Y)(Y)(Y)(Y)(Y)(Y)(Y)(Y)(Y)(Y)

Comment: No luck for me. Not sure why. I haven't had a problem before.

Answer (score 14):

are the images in xcode or in the file system?, i dont see an `--assets-dest` in your bundle parameters

```
react-native bundle  --minify --dev false --assets-dest ./ios --entry-file index.ios.js --platform ios --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle
```

also add the assets folder to xcode like the bundle.

note that the image assets are only copied if they are required correctly, see the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html)

Comment: Thanks! I will give that a whirl!

Comment: the result of this command is: unknown option '--minify', any idea?

Comment: @Moussawi7 the minify flag has been incorporated in the -dev flag

--dev [boolean]   If false, warnings are disabled and the bundle is minified

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in your react native project root:

`react-native bundle --entry-file='./index.js' --bundle-output='./main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios'`

And add a reference of the folder in your project in XCode.

Answer (score 0):

for ios 14 :
go to this directory:
node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image
and open the RCTUIImageViewAnimated.m then add the else condition to this part :

```
if (_currentFrame) {
layer.contentsScale = self.animatedImageScale;
layer.contents = (__bridge id)_currentFrame.CGImage;
} else {
[super displayLayer:layer];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I add the assets folder as a whole in Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources and run this;

npx react-native bundle --platform ios --assets-dest ./ --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle

Hope this helps someone.